# ElasticSearch highlight as anchor with parameter of the result

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-highlight

I want to highlight result of ElasticSearch query by html `<a>` tag with parameter of result for `href` attribute.

Example of highlight query:

```
highlight" : {
    "pre_tags" : ["<a href='xyz.php?no=typeA.Number'>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</a>"],
    "fields" : {
        "*" : {}
    }
}
```

in this example I want to use field `Number` as value for query string `no` inside `href` attribute of tag `<a>`.

How it's possible?

Comment: its not possible right now in elasticsearch to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, what you suggest for this case?